# How can I add different thumbnails when I need to insert multiple video from the playlist to my website?

Tags: youtube-api

How can I add different thumbnails when I need to insert multiple video from the playlist to my website?
For example, now I have such page:
http://i.gyazo.com/1fa3d85b5daf42de1922b302b8d3640c.png

I insert video by using following code:

```html
<iframe width="480" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HN8GBG0JtUA?list=PL-QXPTHVI31NwIGf9XtUbUOEAZv9BQQwv&rel=0" style="margin-right: 15px;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Each video must have it's own thunmnail. How can I do it?
Thank's for help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an individual player for each (or at least some) of the videos, you could remove the `list` parameter:

```html
<iframe width="480" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HN8GBG0JtUA?&rel=0" style="margin-right: 15px;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Or do you want the player to automatically play the next video in the list? Then you could reload the player with a new videoId each time a video ends (with JS).